# Routing and Remote Access: How to configure VPN?

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, rras

My only experience with VPN so far is as a user (e.g. log in to work)

Now I'm trying to set up Windows Server 2003 to connect to a VPN LAN (address space 192.168/16, no default gateway, protocol is PPTP). I want only the 192.168/16 network to go to the VPN connection, the rest should be routed through my server's default gateway.

So I thought I'd be able to do this with 'Routing and Remote Access'. There's a nice wizard where I selected "Secure connection between two private networks". I created a demand-dial device with my VPN credentials, and added a static route to the 192.168/16 network to trigger the DD interface.

I'm able to dial the connection in 'user mode' (with Control Panel/Network Connections/Create a new connection), and it works fine. In the RRAS the connection is 'unreachable' and I get a message box:

> A connection to the remote computer
>   could not be established. You might
>   need to change the network settings
>   for this connection.

In the event viewer I get an error with ID 20111

> A Demand Dial connection to the remote
>   interface VPN on port VPN3-4 was
>   successfully initiated but failed to
>   complete successfully because of the 
>   following error: A connection to the
>   remote computer could not be
>   established. You might need to change
>   the network settings for this
>   connection. For further assistance,
>   click More Info or search Help and
>   Support Center for this error number.

So, what is different between a user-mode VPN connection, and a VPN connection in RRAS? Are there special requirements for the VPN server (e.g. must it be another Win2k3 server) ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this KB is what you're looking for!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247231

Let me know!

Regards,
David.

Comment: No problem! Let me know and if you need a hand, I'll be there.

D.